# HTML and CSS - i can't remove margin

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I would like to put the qr code close to the margin, but I can't remove that white margin. I'm generating it as follows:

[image]

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The margin is part of the image itself: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=https://google.com

Comment: You may be able to solve the problem with `object-fit`: https://jsfiddle.net/g3uo9b67/1/

Comment: An image is _not tabular data_, so you should not be using html tables for layout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cropped your qr code by moving it into div, which is smaller and positions image outside its boundary. Thanks to the overflow hidden, the contents of the image, outside div is cropped.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

.wrapper > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class=wrapper>
          <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow!!! very interesting solution

Comment: @Kudlas Using div as a selector is completely pointless and makes 0 difference to the output, it's just code bloat.

Comment: @SethWarburton yeah, you are right in this case, I started with only div selector and then I appended class and forgot about it. It is now polished, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The white space around the QR code is the margin created by default. You can manage it by passing the `chld` parameter in your URL.

```
chld=<error_correction_level>|<margin>
```

The `error_correction` can be set to "L", which is also by default L, if you don't pass the `chld` parameter. And the `margin` can be any number, remember it is rows not pixels.

So by changing your code to the below will get your desired result.

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}&chld=L|2
```

Try changing the number after `|` in the above code and you'll know the difference.

For reference, go to [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#syntax) and see the `chld=<error_correction_level>|<margin>` section.

Thanks

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class=wrapper>
          <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}&chld=L|2">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer. No hacks required.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    object-fit: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code for generating QR code for my website but i am not getting any margin like that,

instead of using Wrapper and CSS use Style for margins and change chs = 140x140 in the URL.

```
 <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={"Link"}&choe=UTF-8" class="card-img" id="myImg" alt="QR Code" style="float:right;margin-right:15px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This white margin is a part of image which is generated, So If you want to remove white space from image you need to crop that image, and for that you can try this.

```css
.cropImg {
    width: 150px; /* width of container */
    height: 150px; /* height of container */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.cropImg img {
    margin: -35px -35px -35px -25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cropImg">
            <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.qr {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.qr img {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="qr">
        <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl={link}">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```